# Конвертация .py в .exe

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Доброго времени суток. Есть вопрос - "Как конвертировать файл `*.py` в `*.exe` ?" При конвертации простого файла вроде print("hello world") всё работает, но как только конвертирую программу, в которой есть библиотеки(вроде tkinter, pygame и других), ничего не происходит.

В setup.py такой код 
`import os
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python/tcl/tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python/tcl/tk8.6'

buildOptions = dict (
    packages = ['os'],
    excludes = ['tkinter','matplotlib.pyplot','numpy'],
    include_files = ['c:/python/DLLs/tcl86t.dll', 'c:/python/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
    )
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None    


executables = [
    Executable('plot.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='editor',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Использую такие библиотеки:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os 
from tkinter import *
```

При запуске (python.exe setup.py build) получаю .exе,но при запуске такое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще надо в setup.py ещё указывать какие библиотеки ты установил и покажи ошибку, которую ты получаешь